# howto start table in mnesia?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have situation when one of tables rich size 2G and after it I cannot work with this table,

'mynode@localhost' 5> mnesia:dirty_first(my_table).
** exited: {aborted,{badarg,[my_table]}} **

I understand I need apply fragmentation but how to do it in runtime?
And main question is - howto start my_table to reduce its size in runtime? (i mean without restart mnesia)

Comment: I have no choice. I cut file from 2000M to 1999M and repair table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of data are you storing in mnesia ? From what I understand, you are trying to traverse your table , is it ?
If you can decide on what will be the maximum amount of data that will be stored in your database , then you can predecide the number of fragments you need while creating the table.

Else if you need to reconfigure your already fragmented database, then check if the below link helps you ::
http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html

Comment: yes, i try to traverse all records in table and at this moment it is not fragmented at all. Can I fragmente table with data? or I need recreate table with new attributes?

Comment: You can surely create a fragmented table using "frag_properties" while creating the table.
I guess you know how data are accessed from a fragmented database. Mnesia maintains a hash to find in which fragment tha data lies.
I think you can add additional fragments using
mnesia:change_table_frag(my_table,{attr,Val}).
Please check the link I had given you